# Symfony3 PHP7 --- Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name

Tags: php, symfony

I have this class:

```
object(stdClass)#720 (3) {
    ["id"]=> int(1)
    ["name"]=> string(13) "jugador"
    ["club"]=> array(5) {
        ["id"]=> int(1)
        ["nombre"]=> string(5) "levski"
        ["telefono"]=> string(3) "123"
        ["borado"]=> bool(false)
        ["jugadores"]=> array(0) { }
    }
}
object(stdClass)#682 (1) { ["scalar"]=> bool(true) }
```

When I try to do

```
echo($item->name);
```

it returns to me the string **"jugador"** but at the same time I get the

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name

Any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: You posted that you have one class, but your output shows two classes.  Perhaps you are trying to echo the name from the second class?

Comment: you are so right! for some reason i have an extra element in the array I am converting to stdClass which generates to me the error. Thank a lot for that point.